# Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Error for batch element #418: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested

Tags: derby

Exception :
java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Error for batch element #418: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Agent.endBatchedReadChain(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeBatchRequestX(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeBatchX(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Error for batch element #418: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more

Comment: I am facing above exception when inserting the data into the derby db batch wise, the batch size is 1000,and i am seeing this error rarely.so please suggest me how to over come this issue.

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/LockDebugging